# Counting rows with different WHERE and GROUP BY to 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
T1 - id, name, userID (stocks) - not really used in this cased
T2 - id, name, stockID, userID (categories)
T3 - id, name, stockID, categoryID, quality, userID (goods)
```

column "quality" can be "0" (good) or "1" (bad) and each goods (even same sort) = 1 row

this SQL, (this "far" I can get), show only total count of good and bad stuff, and if category exist, but haven't any rows, then it's not shown in final results:

```
SELECT T2.name, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM T3
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.id=T3.categoryID
WHERE T3.stockID=2 GROUP BY T3.categoryID
```

Result:

```
CATEGORY  - TOTAL
category1 - 1237
category2 -  857
category3 -  125
```

category4 is not shown, because no rows exist, but I need every single rows been shown, even if T3 rows doesn't exist and BAD stuff count of course..

Desired result:

```
CATEGORY  - BAD / TOTAL
category1 - 425 / 1237
category2 - 326 /  857
category3 -   0 /  125
category4 -   0 /    0
```

Comment: Where's the sqlfiddle?

Comment: I just finish it, here is test data and Mihai SQL query -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bffb/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T2.name, SUM(CASE WHEN T3.quality=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS BAD,
       COUNT(*)AS TOTAL 
FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.id=T3.categoryID
WHERE t2.stockid=2
GROUP BY T2.name;
```

Comment: Close enough, but still doesn't show not existed rows -> category4 - 0 / 0

Comment: You cant show what doesn't exist, you need a table with all categories existing.Maybe it`s T1.name?

Comment: T1 is only stock.. first create a stock, then category, then goods.. and if you don't create goods, then category is empty, but still exist, because someone create it, and I want to displayed the category as empty or 0 - 0 or whatever.. how can I do that ?

Comment: In what table all 4 categories exist?

Comment: in T2 - categories table

Comment: If those 4 categoreis exist in t2.name this will give you all 4.

Comment: it doesn't.. result: category1 BAD 425 TOTAL 1237, category2 BAD 326 TOTAL 857, category3 BAD 0 TOTAL 125, category4 is missing, is not in result, but is exist in T2 (categories) table

Comment: Show some sample data from both tables in your original question.

Comment: here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bffb/1/0 ... as you can see, category4 and category7 is missing.. they are created and exist, but it's empty and doesn't shown in final result..

Comment: "id" is auto_increment, you can see this in that sqlfiddle example in "CREATE TABLE" SQL query.. what are you looking for ?

Comment: that's not what I want.. category1 and 2 is for stock number 3, and category3 - 7 is for stock number 2.. I want to see result only from stock number 2 and also if is empty or not..

Comment: This means table1 also has to be joined..Add it to the fiddle.

Comment: that's exactly what I want, really thank you for your help and for your time and everything, I really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do the `left join` in the other direction (you could also do a `right outer join`).  And change the `count()` to count matching records:

```
SELECT T2.name, coalesce(SUM(t.3bad), 0) as Bad, COUNT(t3.categoryID) AS TOTAL
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN
     T3
     ON T2.id = T3.categoryID and T3.stockID = 2;
GROUP BY T2.name;
```

Also, it is a good idea to `select` the same fields that are in the `group by` clause.  Really, more than a good idea.  Most databases (and the standard) generally require this.  The MySQL extension to `group by` can cause problems.

Note that I moved the `where` condition into the `on` clause.  This prevents additional filtering that would remove the rows you want.

Comment: This is also only close enough, because this shown everything, even if the goods is in other category and "BAD stuff" count is missing..